# Ember.js + Ember Data returns OPTIONS file:///C:/posts net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on load

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I'm fairly new to Ember.js, so this might be a stupid question, but it's completely stumped me, and I can't find any resources on it.

I've set up a basic Ember.js application with Ember Data, and have been attempting to add a basic `Post` model to the application. Everything is fine until I try to add a route for displaying the posts.

When I navigate to the route path, nothing renders, and the Chrome Dev Console reads:

```
OPTIONS file:///C:/posts net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Error while processing route: posts
```

This is my main Application .js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapater = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("about");
  this.route("fourOhFour", { path: "*path"});
  this.resource("posts", {path: '/posts'});
});



App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
    return this.store.find('post'); 
  }
});

App.GravatarImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    size: 200,
    email: '',
    tagName: 'span',

  gravatarUrl: function()
    {
        var email = this.get('email'),
            size = this.get('size');
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hex_md5(email) + '?s=' + size + "&d=retro";
    }.property('email','size')
});


Ember.Handlebars.helper('format-date', function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});

var showdown = new Showdown.converter();

Ember.Handlebars.helper('format-markdown', function(inp){
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(inp));
});
```

And this is the separate Post file, including the fixtures.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Hello World!",
    username: "CalmBit",
    email: "EB5473@gmail.com",
    body: "This is a test!"
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Hello Again World!",
    username: "CalmBit",
    email: "EB5473@gmail.com",
    body: "This is another test!"
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: "Goodbye World!",
    username: "CalmBit",
    email: "EB5473@gmail.com",
    body: "This is the last test!"
}
];
```

More information can be provided. Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: Part of the problem seems to be that `store` is undefined for the `Post` model. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be automatically rectified, or if I need to manually define it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your code through a webserver. You are loading it into your browser directly from the filesystem. Make sure your address bar shows an `http` or `https` URI.

Comment: Well, that _changed_ the problem. Now it's returning a `GET http://localhost/posts 404 (Not Found)`. But I'm a step closer to figuring it out, so thank you!

Comment: if you're on cli, it's `localhost:4200` by default